# How format Rails form field with CSS/Bootstrap?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-4

I've tried a lot of research and tinkering and I just can't get my Rails view to format a form with Bootstrap or CSS. I know that the Bootstrap classes could be affecting it or the CSS.

What I'm trying to do is just create a two column, side by side container. With an image in one column next to the form in the other. Both the same size.

I've tried the expected and researched:
Container with row with two columns. One column as the form and the second column as the image.

Instead the form is acting like it is fluid and taking up the entire page width and the columns are stacking vertically, instead of side by side.

I want it took look like this:
[image]

```
<div class="container d-flex">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      
        <%= form_with(model: car, local: true) do |form| %>

          <%= hidden_field_tag "car[login]", exists ? "#{@car.login}" : "#{@current_user.login}"  %>

          <div class="field">
            <%= form.label :model, class: "h3" %><br>
            <%= form.text_field :model, id: :car_model, class: "form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= form.label :year, class: "h3" %><br>
            <%= form.number_field :year, id: :car_year, class: "form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= form.label :color, class: "h3" %><br>
            <%= form.text_field :color, id: :car_color, class: "form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" %>
          </div>

          <div class="field">
            <%= form.label :licence_plate, class: "h3" %><br>
            <%= form.text_field :licence_plate, id: :car_licence_plate, class: "form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" %>
          </div>

          <div class="actions">
            <%= form.button "<h3>#{submit_text}</h3>".html_safe, class: "btn btn-success btn-sm" %>
          </div>

        <% end %>
        <div class="col">
           # img source here
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for bootstrap forms, your label and input should be wrapped by a `.form-group` element, not a `.field` one.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Do something like:

```
<div class="form-group field">
  <%= form.label :licence_plate, class: "h3" %><br>
  <%= form.text_field :licence_plate, id: :car_licence_plate, class: "form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" %>
</div>
```